# If Statement with multiple criteria using Or's Method Errors

Tags: excel, vba

I have an if statement that checks if the sheet is the one i'm looking for to use in a for loop.  The statement has multiple conditions that can satisfy the statement.  When I run it, it gives me an error

Run-time error '438':

Object doesn't support this property or method

Here is the code in question.

```
Application.Sheets.Add(After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets _
(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.count)).Name = "Data Sheet"

Dim WSds As Worksheet
Dim WScolumbo As Worksheet
Dim WSscm As Worksheet
Dim WSselexx As Worksheet
Dim WSsashclamp As Worksheet
Dim WSframeclamp As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim k As Long
Dim countrows As Long
Dim countcolumns As Long
Dim Sheetscount As Long
Dim WSdsindexx As Long


Set WSds = Worksheets("Data Sheet")
Set WScolumbo = Worksheets("Columbo (sash)")
Set WSscm = Worksheets("SCM Pratix Z2 (Sash)")
Set WSselexx = Worksheets("Selex PAL (Sash)")
Set WSsashclamp = Worksheets("Sash Clamp")
Set WSframeclamp = Worksheets("Frame Clamp")

countrows = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
countcolumns = ActiveSheet.Cells(Columns.count, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
WSdsindexx = 1

For Sheetcount = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.count
    If ((Worksheets(Sheetcount) = WScolumbo) Or _
    (Worksheets(Sheetcount) = WSscm) Or _
    (Worksheets(Sheetcount) = WSselexx) Or _
    (Worksheets(Sheetcount) = WSsashclamp) Or _
    (Worksheets(Sheetcount) = WSframeclamp)) Then
        For i = 2 To countcolumns
            For k = 1 To countrows
                If Worksheets(Sheetcount).Cells(k, i).Value = "Machine Cycle" Then
                    WSds.Cells(WSdsindexx, 3).Value = Worksheets(Sheetcount).Cells(k, i).Offset(1, 1).Value
                    WSds.Cells(WSdsindexx, 2) = Worksheets(Sheetcount).Cells(k, i).Value
                    WSds.Cells(WSdsindexx, 1) = Worksheets(Sheetcount).Name
                ElseIf Worksheets(Sheetcount).Cells(k, i).Value = "Swap Out Parts and Adjust Size" Then WSds.Cells(WSdsindexx, 3).Value = Worksheets(Sheetcount).Cells(k, i).Offset(1, 1).Value
                    WSds.Cells(WSdsindexx, 2) = Worksheets(Sheetcount).Cells(k, i).Value
                    WSds.Cells(WSdsindexx, 1) = Worksheets(Sheetcount).Name
                ElseIf Worksheets(Sheetcount).Cells(k, i).Value = "Unload/Load" Then WSds.Cells(WSdsindexx, 3).Value = Worksheets(Sheetcount).Cells(k, i).Offset(1, 1).Value
                    WSds.Cells(WSdsindexx, 2) = Worksheets(Sheetcount).Cells(k, i).Value
                    WSds.Cells(WSdsindexx, 1) = Worksheets(Sheetcount).Name
                ElseIf Worksheets(Sheetcount).Cells(k, i).Value = "Take Parts Out and Put New In" Then WSds.Cells(WSdsindexx, 3).Value = Worksheets(Sheetcount).Cells(k, i).Offset(1, 1).Value
                    WSds.Cells(WSdsindexx, 2) = Worksheets(Sheetcount).Cells(k, i).Value
                    WSds.Cells(WSdsindexx, 1) = Worksheets(Sheetcount).Name
                ElseIf Worksheets(Sheetcount).Cells(k, i).Value = "Top Clamp" Then WSds.Cells(WSdsindexx, 3).Value = Worksheets(Sheetcount).Cells(k, i).Offset(1, 1).Value
                    WSds.Cells(WSdsindexx, 2) = Worksheets(Sheetcount).Cells(k, i).Value
                    WSds.Cells(WSdsindexx, 1) = Worksheets(Sheetcount).Name
                ElseIf Worksheets(Sheetcount).Cells(k, i).Value = "Bottom Clamp" Then WSds.Cells(WSdsindexx, 3).Value = Worksheets(Sheetcount).Cells(k, i).Offset(1, 1).Value
                    WSds.Cells(WSdsindexx, 2) = Worksheets(Sheetcount).Cells(k, i).Value
                    WSds.Cells(WSdsindexx, 1) = Worksheets(Sheetcount).Name
                ElseIf Worksheets(Sheetcount).Cells(k, i).Value = "Load Top" Then WSds.Cells(WSdsindexx, 3).Value = Worksheets(Sheetcount).Cells(k, i).Offset(1, 1).Value
                    WSds.Cells(WSdsindexx, 2) = Worksheets(Sheetcount).Cells(k, i).Value
                    WSds.Cells(WSdsindexx, 1) = Worksheets(Sheetcount).Name
                ElseIf Worksheets(Sheetcount).Cells(k, i).Value = "Load Bottom" Then WSds.Cells(WSdsindexx, 3).Value = Worksheets(Sheetcount).Cells(k, i).Offset(1, 1).Value
                    WSds.Cells(WSdsindexx, 2) = Worksheets(Sheetcount).Cells(k, i).Value
                    WSds.Cells(WSdsindexx, 1) = Worksheets(Sheetcount).Name
                ElseIf Worksheets(Sheetcount).Cells(k, i).Value = "Unload Top" Then WSds.Cells(WSdsindexx, 3).Value = Worksheets(Sheetcount).Cells(k, i).Offset(1, 1).Value
                    WSds.Cells(WSdsindexx, 2) = Worksheets(Sheetcount).Cells(k, i).Value
                    WSds.Cells(WSdsindexx, 1) = Worksheets(Sheetcount).Name
                ElseIf Worksheets(Sheetcount).Cells(k, i).Value = "Unload Bottom" Then WSds.Cells(WSdsindexx, 3).Value = Worksheets(Sheetcount).Cells(k, i).Offset(1, 1).Value
                    WSds.Cells(WSdsindexx, 2) = Worksheets(Sheetcount).Cells(k, i).Value
                    WSds.Cells(WSdsindexx, 1) = Worksheets(Sheetcount).Name
                Else: MsgBox "No Matches Criteria"
                End If
            Next k
        Next i
    Else: MsgBox "No Matches Sheet"
    End If
Next Sheetcount
```

The first if statement is the one that is giving me the error.

Comment: Try comparing the names of the sheets instead of the actual sheet.  `(Worksheets(Sheetcount).Name = WScolumbo.Name)` and so on.

Comment: @ScottCraner Okay I figured it was either a syntax error or my worksheet names aren't being recognized.  I'll play with it quick.

Comment: @ScottCraner You were right.  Did you want to put the answer up? otherwise i'll answer it.

Comment: Feel free to answer.  I am happy to have helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I Got it figured out with the help of @ScottCraner

In order to compare sheets, you have to use the sheet names or their index numbers.

In my case I used names, so

```
If ((Worksheets(Sheetcount).Name = WScolumbo.Name) Or _
    (Worksheets(Sheetcount).Name = WSscm.Name) Or _
    (Worksheets(Sheetcount).Name = WSselexx.Name) Or _
    (Worksheets(Sheetcount).Name = WSsashclamp.Name) Or _
    (Worksheets(Sheetcount).Name = WSframeclamp.Name)) Then
```

worked for me.

In the Case of index numbers,

You would have to

```
Set WScolumbo = Worksheets(1)
```

instead of

```
Set Wscolumbo = Worksheets("Columbo (sash)")
```

At least i'm pretty sure that should work.